# Add data to an existing user profile: React, Javascript, Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have an app that allows a user to register for an account and then do various things once they have logged in. Once they have logged in , one of the things they can do is create a todo list.  I want this todo list to be able to be recalled by the user later on, but I can't figure out how to save it to the database with the specific user who is logged in.  I am 100% noob with firebase/react.  So far I can get the list to save to a totally new document in the cloud database, but not update the with a specific user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the user is logged in

Docs for that https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
if (user) {
// User is logged in
} else {
// No user logged in
}
```

2. Read the todo, I guess it would a state of a component
3. Write the state to firebase, if would prefer firestore. This all will be inside the `if(user)`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const docRef = doc(db, 'todoList', uid);
setDoc(cityRef, { todoList: todoListState }, { merge: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new key in your database with the uid of the user and push the list there. For example:

```
db.ref('/users').child(`${user.uid}`).set({list: theList})
```

Comment: it tells me here that db.ref is not a function :(

Comment: I think firebase just recently updated their API so you may you need to use something like ``set(ref(db, `/users/${newUser.user.uid}`),{list: theList})``

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using firestore as the database in firebase. Firestore saves all the information as JSON Tree with the hierarchy of Collection-document which means you can have multiple document inside a collection and once again each document can have multiple collection in them.

To save the TODO information in the Firestore first you need to think how you are going to structure your collection and document for the whole application. This structure will also depend on how to secure the data for each user.

Following is an example of the structure you could have for the database for TODO list

/users/{firebaseUID}/todolist/mylist

in the above structure users and todolist are collection and firebaseUID and mylist are document names. I have given the firebaseUID inside the curly braces because it will be different for each user

To add or update the list for each of the users you will pass the following information

```
const myListData = // Something
const userId = // ger the data from firebase.auth().currentUser.uid or other options
// hope you know how to get the object of firestore from React Firestore package
// Create
Firestore.doc(`/users/${userId}/todolist/mylist`).create(myListData);

//Update
Firestore.doc(`/users/${userId}/todolist/mylist`).update(myListData);
```

Comment: I did manage to get the userId in , but I am getting an error that Firestore.doc is not a function.  It will let me use firestore.collection but it saves wrong, it creates a new document as the user id